# Github Action fails: 'git-lfs' is not on your path

Tags: git, github, github-actions, commitizen

I am using the following Github action:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  bump_version:
    if: "!startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, 'bump:')"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: "Bump version and create changelog with commitizen"
    steps:
      - name: Check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: "${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}"
      - id: cz
        name: Create bump and changelog
        uses: commitizen-tools/commitizen-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          lfs: true
      - name: Print Version
        run: echo "Bumped to version ${{ steps.cz.outputs.version }}"
```

The step `cz` that makes a commit has the option `lfs: true` but when the Github action is executing I get the following error:

```
Current branch master is up to date.

This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.

error: failed to push some refs to
```

How to can I solve this error in order to allow that `cz` makes a commit?

Comment: That action doesn't have an `lfs` parameter, see [here](https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen-action/blob/master/action.yml). Did you mean to set that parameter on the `checkout` step?

Comment: I guessed that lfs:true was a github action option not a particular github-action option @BenjaminW.

Comment: The error is the message posted `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/....'` @matt

Comment: It's not a global option. The `action.yml` file of an action defines what parameters are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `lfs: true` parameter to the `checkout` action and then explicitly checkout LFS files:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      lfs: true

  - name: Checkout LFS objects
    run: git lfs checkout
```

According to the `actions/checkout` documentation:

```
# Whether to download Git-LFS files
# Default: false
lfs: ''
```

`git lfs checkout` - downloads and checkouts large files from a Git LFS repository.

In addition, there is a GH Action that provides a caching mechanism for LFS files - [Cached LFS checkout](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cached-lfs-checkout).

Additional references:

- https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen-action/issues/7
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466160/7328018

Comment: I solved with cached, thanks.